# Problem with run docker container contains golang project

Tags: linux, docker, go

I experience some problem when attempt to run a my docker image that contain golang application.
This Is an error: `enter code here`standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"

This Is my environment:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/nikolaj//home/nikolaj/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/nikolaj/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/nikolaj/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/snap/go/4765"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/snap/go/4765/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build908015468=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"

go environment : GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/nikolaj//home/nikolaj/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/nikolaj/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"

GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/nikolaj/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/snap/go/4765"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/snap/go/4765/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build838573681=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12.0

WORKDIR /app

ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/vk_acceptor/

ADD . $SRC_DIR

RUN cd $SRC_DIR; env; goenv; export GO111MODULE=on; go get -u; go build -o application; cp application /app/

RUN chmod +x application

ENTRYPOINT ["./application"]
```

After formatting `RUN command` it looks like this: `RUN cd $SRC_DIR && env && goenv && export GO111MODULE=on && go get -u && go build -o application && cp application /app/`

Output of `docker build .` command :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.067MB
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.12.0
 ---> cee68f119e19
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5bffbbf8f161
Step 3/7 : ENV SRC_DIR=/go/src/vk_acceptor/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf145f38f8db
Step 4/7 : ADD . $SRC_DIR
 ---> 766466f20647
Step 5/7 : RUN cd $SRC_DIR && env && goenv && export GO111MODULE=on && go get -u && go build -o application && cp application /app/
 ---> Running in 7aeb8905c137
HOSTNAME=7aeb8905c137
SRC_DIR=/go/src/vk_acceptor/
HOME=/root
OLDPWD=/app
PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
GOPATH=/go
PWD=/go/src/vk_acceptor
GOLANG_VERSION=1.12
/bin/sh: 1: goenv: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c cd $SRC_DIR && env && goenv && export GO111MODULE=on && go get -u && go build -o application && cp application /app/' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: What does `file ./application` print? Do you run this container on a amd64 system?

Comment: Are building the exe outside of Docker? If so, I'd suggest building within the Docker build itself to ensure consistent library linkage from known Linux images.

Comment: Application builds inside the container, and as seem without any issues.

The output:
docker build -t vkspotter .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.067MB
Step 1/7 : FROM golang:1.12.0
 ---> cee68f119e19
...
(skip some steps)
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["./application"]
 ---> Running in 1feb2636c88f
Removing intermediate container 1feb2636c88f
 ---> 8c5011c23472
Successfully built 8c5011c23472
Successfully tagged vkspotter:latest

Comment: @tkausl
Yes i do run the app on amd64 sys, my spec: Intel i5, Ubuntu 19.04.
Can you please clarificate where  should i run the `file ./application` command ?

Comment: You can not be sure that there are no issues, since you are ignoring the return values of the respective commands in the long `RUN` label. Connect each command with an `&&` instead of a `;`and [add the output to your question by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59008571/edit)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg you was absolutely right, there is issue with `go env`.
I suppose that image is used for creating container (`golang:1.12.0`) does not have bin for go env command, can it be so?

Comment: `goenv` != `go env` (note the blank). `docker run golang:1.12.0  go env` works as expected.

Comment: Bit of [additional advice in a gist](https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/6af4cb8edc56a517b599a59a6b1b767e).

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg
Thanks for replying, i make my Dockerfile looks like your template, and just remove `goenv` command, so my first issue was resolved.
But i faced a some other problem `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`, i searched information about it, and all i found was that occurs when you attempt to run a container with an architecture different from your host architecture.I believe this is a topic for a separate topic, right

Comment: Most likely. I exclusively use 64bit Linux for creating and running images. I will doublecheck the gist and comment there accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"` error occurs for various reasons, and not only when you try to launch an image with an architecture different from your host machine, as many forums say.
In my case, this error occurred due to the fact that the bundled program was placed in the wrong directory in the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output error, you can clearly see the error message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: goenv: not found
```

I presume you wanted to type `go env` in your command?

Comment: Yes it is right, but in above thread i was helped with that. and now i have new issue.
The  error is: `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error" `, i searched information about it, and all i found was that occurs when you attempt to run a container with an architecture different from your host architecture.